# API returns a incomplete JSON files

Tags: java, json

I am using the Wargaming API for accessing game data and every time I download one of their JSON files in Java it is never complete no matter the filesize.

I think its related to my way of reading from streams:

```
//variables:
int data;
InputStreamReader isr;
PrintWriter pw;
//Read from file:
while ((data = isr.read()) != -1)
{
pw.print((char) data);
}
```

The InputStreamReader comes from a URLConnection.getInputStream() associated with the URL to the API.

So how do I read from the stream without either it breaking or encountering a end of file?

Comment: Take a look at BufferedReader. Try wrapping your InputStreamReader with one and do your reads via the BufferedReader. Also reading a single character at a time is rather inefficient.  Take a look at the alternate read method that takes a char[] so that you can read more characters at one time.

Comment: I took your advice and changed 'while ((data  = isr.read()) != -1)' to 'while ((data = br.readLine()) != null)'  and wrapped my input stream reader with a buffered reader.  But alas, I still am getting incomplete files.

Comment: if you save the files on a disc, are they complete?

Comment: No. The PrintWriter pw points to a file that already exists, and the data will cut off randomly, and I have looked through the files trying to find a pattern, but it cuts off at no certain length and during both identifiers and values (In JSON).  The runtime comes back with no errors. **NOTE:** I have used the api in my browser and the files are complete.

Answer (score 0):

I use  `org.apache.commons.io.IOUtils` with `Gson`, this set has never disappointed me.

```
    InputStream stream = connection.getInputStream(); // or getErrorStream()
    StringWriter writer = new StringWriter();
    IOUtils.copy(stream, writer, "UTF-8");
    String response = writer.toString();
    Entity entity = new Gson().fromJson(response,  Entity.class);
```

Comment: Could you include a link to the javadoc? Also I am using json simple and have no problem reading the data, its just incomplete.